# Where does FFMPEG store temporary files in Linux?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, filesystems, conversion

I quit the conversion of a very large file in ffmpeg. The incomplete file is taking up almost 200GB on my disk but it does not exist in the directory I was working in and I can't find it anywhere (it is not in the ffmpeg folder). Where does ffmpeg store temporary/incomplete files, and how can I locate this missing file?

(I've had a similar problem in the past when running a file recovery program - I canceled the recovery and the files disappeared. They are simply taking up "ghost" space on the directory and can't be located.)

I've tried searching for the filename, clearing the trash, rebooting.

Comment: From what path did you run your ffmpeg command and what was your ffmpeg command?

Comment: From the same path that I was working in - user@computer:~Folder/SubFolder$ ffmpeg -i "[This is the file].mp3" -c:a wav -acodec pcm_f64le -ar 41000 "${i%.*}.wav"

Comment: *ffmpeg* generally does not use temporary files at all. The output file may not have been properly unlinked. Try `fsck`. // Also, please add all clarification directly to your question. You can edit it anytime.